# Python threading - what's the difference?

Tags: python, multithreading

Could anyone explain why this code prints nothing:

```
import threading

def threadCode1(): 
    while True:
        pass      

def threadCode2():
    while True:
        pass


thread = threading.Thread(target=threadCode1())
thread2 = threading.Thread(target=threadCode2())
thread.start()
print('test')
thread2.start()
```

But if I remove the brackets:

```
thread = threading.Thread(target=threadCode1)
thread2 = threading.Thread(target=threadCode2)
```

It does print 'test'? That's quite a surprising result for me.

Comment: In the () case, you are calling the threadCodeN functions before creating the thread. In the case without (), you are passing those functions as arguments to the thread, for the thread to execute them later.

Comment: Why is that surprising to you?

Answer (score 5):

Because, when you first evaluate the line with the thread call:

```
thread = threading.Thread(target=threadCode1())
```

The first thing that line does is execute `threadCode1()` which makes the program jump to the `threadCode1` function body, which is an infinite loop and the execution will never make it out of the function and execute the next lines in the main procedure.

If you change `threadCode1` to this:

```
def threadCode1(): 
    while True:
        print 'threadCode1'
```

You'll notice how it endlessly loops printing `threadCode1`.

Comment: After the threadCode1() is executed, does it eventually create and start the thread `thread`? Assuming the threadCode1 didn't contain an infinite loop.

Comment: It doesn't, the `threadCode1()` call will make the program jump to the `threadCode1()` method and will remain there forever (because is an infinite loop)

Comment: When you set target=threadCode1, you are in fact directing the thread the execute the target method **when you .start() the thread**.

Comment: @user216094 Assuming the threadCode1 didn't contain an infinite loop then yes, it will eventually create a thread (although I'm not sure what the consequences are, because Thread expects a callabale)

Comment: Yes, because the functions don't return anything, you are basically setting the targets to None.

Answer (score 2):

When you start the threads, they run under a *separate thread of control* than your program. That means they are doing their own thing (looping forever) and your main process can continue doing what it wants. As noted above, appending parens in the first example actually calls the function **within the main process**. If you instead type

```
thread = threading.Thread(target=threadCode1)
thread2 = threading.Thread(target=threadCode2)
thread.start()
thread.join()
print('test')
```

You will experience what you expect to happen, since the main process is then waiting for the thread to finish.